# The fixed point $F(0,2)$ lies inside the circle $x^2+y^2=16$. Find the locus of the midpoint M of AB.

Tags: polynomials

The fixed point $F(0,2)$ lies inside the circle $x^2+y^2=16$. A variable line l through $F$ meets the circle at A and B. Find the locus of the midpoint M of AB.

For this question I let line $y=mx+2$ intersect with the circle and I found $x=\frac{-2m}{1+m^2}$ and $y=\frac{2}{1+m^2}$ but I can't make the locus in terms of $x$ and $y$. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try m=$tan(\omega)$

Comment: How do you represent the horizontal line through $F$ with that equation?

Answer (score 0):

$O(0,0)$ is center of the circle and point $M$ is midpoint of $[AB]$. $OM \perp AB$. That is $\angle OMF = 90^\circ $ is constant. Also $|OF|=2$ units constant. Locus of vertex of constant $\angle OMF$ is a circle that it's diameter is $[OF]$. Therefore locus is $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$.

Also, this is eligble with your $x=\dfrac{-2m}{1+m^2}$, $y=\dfrac{2}{1+m^2}$.

$x^2+(y-1)^2=\left(\dfrac{-2m}{1+m^2}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{1-m^2}{1+m^2}\right)^2 = \dfrac{4m^2 + 1 -2m^2 +m^4}{(1+m^2)^2} = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

By symmetry (around the perpendicular bisector of $AB$, which is a diameter of the initial circle), the midpoint of $AB$ is also the midpoint between $F$ and the *other* point of $l$ that is exactly $2$ units from the origin.

In other words, the desired locus consists of each point on the smaller circle $x^2+y^2=2^2$ moved halfway towards $F$. This is again a circle, with radius $1$ and centered at $(0,1)$.